# Does downloading to an external or network-attached drive create meaningful wear on your main hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, download, nas

I'm about to buy a new laptop. I anticipate wanting to download some video (for one thing, higher quality than just streaming it). Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/48431/does-downloading-torrents-cause-excessive-wear-on-hard-drives/446096#446096) I'm concerned that the downloading may wear my drive (an SSD) out faster and am looking for advice. I won't be a super-heavy user: let's say I'll download an hour a day of video. Which of the following is a good approach?

1. Don't worry about it.
2. Make the download location an external drive, either a USB key or a regular hard drive, as suggested on the thread I linked to above
3. Make the download location a network-attached drive
4. Something else?

What I don't know about #2 and #3 is whether either or both of them stress the built-in drive on my notebook. Are little pieces of the download written down a temporary directory on that drive (potentially even as virtual memory--I'm not at all sure whether this is used meaningfully these days) before finding their way to their ultimate home? Are #2 and #3 different as far as this goes?

I guess I should ask the same question about streaming video. Does streaming create a workout for your drive or is everything kept in RAM?

Other relevant threads [here](https://superuser.com/questions/442473/excessive-torrenting-and-hard-drive-health) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/161145/is-it-ok-to-use-bittorrent-on-solid-state-drives-ssd?rq=1) imply that #2 is okay by virtue of suggesting it but don't address #3 and aren't explicit on the subject of what behaviors create strain for drive A even if the ultimate destination of a download is drive B.

Comment: The answer is #1.  By the time you wear it out, you've probably already got a new computer anyway. ;)  Why not use a resource monitor to monitor what/how much disk activity is happening on the drive you're concerned about?

Comment: The first question you linked actually tries to explain wear, but it refers mostly to HDD's. As SSD have a different wear pattern (defined in maximum read/write cycles), the "rule" would be to minimize IO to and from the disk. The disk is used more than you think, but, as @techie007 said, it is not something a regular user should concern.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. It would take more than a decade of heavy use to wear out a modern SSD, and by that time it'll be obsolete anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly the answer I was hoping for. Does anyone have a link to any study or other information establishing that wear is not an issue for normal users?